# flutter sensor stop listening to sensor event

Tags: flutter

I am using very simple solution for listening to sensor events and printing on a simple flutter app with [Sensor](https://pub.dev/packages/sensors) package. I am using `WidgetsBindingObserver` and based on lifecycle events I want to listen and stop, like andorid.
I can start listening to sensor value changes with `accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event){}` method mentioned in readme. But this doesn't work from resumed state but works from `initState()`.

How can I start and stop this listening properly?

code:

```
 @override
  void initState(){
    print("We are on initstate.");
    super.initState();
    accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
      print(event);
      setSensorValue(event.toString());
    }); // [UserAccelerometerEvent (x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)]
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    print("We are on initstate.");

  }
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state){
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        userAccelerometerEvents.listen((UserAccelerometerEvent event) {
          print(event);
        }); // [UserAccelerometerEvent (x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)]
        break;

      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        //cancel listening userAccelerometerEvents.
        break;

      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:

        break;

      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        // TODO: Handle this case.
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap "accelerometerEvents.listen" with _streamSubscriptions.add(accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {}).

**For init listen:**

```
_streamSubscriptions
    .add(accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
  setState(() {
    _accelerometerValues = <double>[event.x, event.y, event.z];
  });
}));
```

**For stop listen:**

```
for (StreamSubscription<dynamic> subscription in _streamSubscriptions) {
  subscription.cancel();
}
```

Full Example: https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/sensors/example

Comment: this reference is outdated now